# Dynamic Horizontal List View in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I need to integrate the Dynamic horizontal listview in my project. I found this concept below blog on the website. But I confused this code to integrate into my project. Kindly suggest me an idea to anyone. I need this image type grid or horizontal listview( https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvJZE.png).

**Mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
public void SetupUserStack()
{


    ---------- issue in _itemSelectCommand in my code

    cButtonList.Add(new CircleButton(_itemSelectCommand)

     { CircleSize = otherCircleSize, CircleFontSize = 35, Text = initials, BackgroundColor = Color.White, TextColor = ourBlue, BorderColor = ourBlue, BorderWidth = 1.5 });
    var b2 = new Button() { Text = lname, TextColor = ourBlue };

    //otherGrid.Children.Add(LargeCB, 0, 0);


    otherGrid.Children.Add(cButtonList[i], 0, 0);


    otherGrid.Children.Add(b2, 0, 1);


    UserStack.Children.Add(otherGrid);

}
```

Blog I refer: [horizontal-list-view-with-circular-button-styling-in-xamarin-forms](http://matthewboroczky.com/horizontal-list-view-with-circular-button-styling-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: What do you really want? A  horizontal listview? Any requirement?

Comment: i attached the below blog website for reference horizontal listview can u check that?

Comment: I did not know but how to integrate that blog website  code into my project in MVVM structure

Comment: Use a collectionView instead and then bind the itemSource to the property in your ViewModel.

Comment: can u gave me idea to integrate below reference to my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is the another way to achieve the same thing. Xamarin forms now support the `Bindable Layouts`

**XAML Code:**

```
 <ScrollView  
   Orientation="Horizontal" 
   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Default">
     <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding LogoImages}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image
                                HeightRequest="25"
                                Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                Source="{Binding logoImage}">
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

Here is more information with the example :

[Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)

Comment: You check that blog I need that type of horizontal scroll view. but I do not know that the blog code MVVM process to integrate into with my project.

Comment: You don't have set everything dynamically. Just design the XAML and bind the list of the model. that's all

Comment: can u explain briefly? because I am new to xamarin this is my first project so only ask if u don't mind plz help me

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-3-5-a-little-bindable-love/ here is the example which can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use a [collectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-list) to create a horizontal-list would be easier and faster, for example:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       WidthRequest="60" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />

                //...your layout

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The `Monkeys` should be a list that in your ViewModel.

You can check the sample with MVVM structure here:[collectionviewdemos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/)

In your linking blog, he creates the grid dynamically with the `users.Count` and I think it hard to integrate his code to MVVM structure.

Comment: i need not sample horizontal list or collectview. i need dynamically when button click items add in horizontal list. that add button also in horizontal list. how to do this?

Comment: @jelinTirsha When you click the add button, add new user to _users in the blog and call page.SetupUserStack(_users);.

Comment: i already integrate this blog but below somehow to call this my code                       cButtonList.Add(new CircleButton(ItemSelectCommand) { CircleSize = otherCircleSize, CircleFontSize = 35, Text = initials, BackgroundColor = Color.White, TextColor = ourBlue, BorderColor = ourBlue, BorderWidth = 1.5 });
var b2 = new Button() { Text = lname, TextColor = ourBlue };
 
//otherGrid.Children.Add(LargeCB, 0, 0);
otherGrid.Children.Add(cButtonList[i], 0, 0);
 
otherGrid.Children.Add(b2, 0, 1);
 
UserStack.Children.Add(otherGrid);

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your code there? Tell us where is the problem and what you need.

Comment: @jelinTirsha I still can't get your point, what is the issue in _itemSelectCommand?

Comment: The name '_itemSelectCommand' does not exist in the current context is mainpage xaml.cs

Comment: Why you need to add _itemSelectCommand as parameter when initialize the new CircleButton?